# How to handle equivalent objects without a shared interface

Tags: java, generics, proxy

I have a piece of code that I would like to generalize but I am not sure how to implement.
My program deals with a number of JAXBElement classes that have the same getter/setter but do not share an interface, and that need a property to be set before sending them to a web service.
The number of classes of the same type might grow in the near future.
Can this be generalized by generics or do I need dynamic proxies?

```
public class ServiceClient1 {
    public Response getResponse(ReqObject1 req1) {
        req1.getValue().setConfig("john","doe");
        return client.target(endpoint).request(MediaType.TEXT_XML).post(Entity.entity(req1, MediaType.TEXT_XML);
    }
    public RespObject1 readResponse(Response resp1) {
        return resp1.readEntity(RespObject1.class);
    }
}
```

into something like

```
public class ServiceClient {
    public <T> Response getResponse(T req) {
        req.getValue().setConfig("john","doe");
        return client.target(endpoint).request(MediaType.TEXT_XML).post(Entity.entity(req, MediaType.TEXT_XML);
    }
    public <T> T readResponse(Response resp) {
        return resp.readEntity(T.class);// ???
    }
}
```

Comment: If your objects don't share any interfaces or have the same parent, you can't use generics. May be you should consider to use reflection.

Comment: Or would I need proxies to call the same method on a different class type and have the proxies implement the same interface?

Comment: Proxies an object need the object implement an interface, you can refer to java doc of `Proxy.newProxyInstance()` for further use.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. 
I need to configure a request object that is sent to a webservice and process the corresponding response.
So I can imagine that writing a proxy for each request class and have the proxies share an interface could generalise the setConfig method but how do I generalise the response type?

Comment: I think maybe it should be a combination of proxies that share an interface, with a generic method.
The problem is that the object returned by the JAXBElement getValue() method should be proxied also, so another InvocationHandler and interface..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Handling getResponse()

**Option 1:**
If it is ok for your request classes to implement a common interface, this method can be entirely handled using *Generics*.

*Interface and Classes Definitions:*

```
interface Configurable {
    void setConfig(String s1, String s2);
}

public class Req1 implements Configurable {
    @Override
    public void setConfig(String s1, String s2) {
    }
}

public class Req2 implements Configurable {
    @Override
    public void setConfig(String s1, String s2) {
    }
}
```

*getResponse() Implementation:*

```
public <T extends Configurable> Response getResponse(JAXBElement<T> req) {
    req.getValue()
       .setConfig("john", "doe");
    return client.target(endpoint)
                 .request(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                 .post(Entity.entity(req, MediaType.TEXT_XML));
}
```

*Note:* As per your example, looks like the input argument is always of type `JAXBElement`.

---

**Option 2:**
If your unable to make all request classes implement `Configurable`, we need to use reflection to generalize the method.

```
public Response getResponse(JAXBElement<?> req) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object instance = req.getValue();
    Method m = instance.getClass()
                       .getMethod("setConfig", String.class, String.class);
    m.invoke(instance, "john", "doe");
    return client.target(endpoint)
                 .request(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                 .post(Entity.entity(req, MediaType.TEXT_XML));
}
```

*Note:* For brevity sake, I have made the method re-throw the exceptions. We can use custom exception and handle it appropriately.

---

#### Handling readResponse()

This method can be entirely handled using *Generics*. Just need to pass 1 more parameter for the return type.

```
public <T> T readResponse(Response response, Class<T> cls) {
    return response.readEntity(cls);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Prasanna.
The reflection solution may be a good alternative to wrapper classes that implement a shared interface.